# How can I retrieve each ArrayList of custom objects then each object from ArrayList of custom objects without Jackson?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arraylist

I can retrieve objects from the outer JSON but I can not retrieve data from the nested JSON.

How can I retrieve each ArrayList of custom objects then each object from ArrayList of custom objects of nested JSON?

I have attempted to use parser library Jackson Json but I am new to Android and as the project uses multiple ArrayList made up of linked classes and custom object using Jackson means to many complicated changes to my HTTPCall class and various associated inner handler classes.

I've included the JSON I'm trying to parse and the Class in which I attempted to access the nested JSON.

But when parsing only empty brackets: [] or array location is returned: appName.classNameArrayName@ArraylocationInNumbers33129726498

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "date": "20121212",
        "summary": [
            {
                "activity": "walking",
                "group": "walking",
                "duration": 3333,
                "distance": 3333,
                "steps": 3333,
                "calories": 300
            },
            {
                "activity": "walking_on_treadmill",
                "group": "walking",
                "duration": 270,
                "steps": 303,
                "calories": 30
            },
            {
                "activity": "transport",
                "group": "transport",
                "duration": 1124,
                "distance": 8443
            },
            {
                "activity": "underground",
                "group": "transport",
                "duration": 1003,
                "distance": 8058
            },
            {
                "activity": "zumba",
                "duration": 570,
                "calories": 200
            }
        ],
        "segments": [
            {
                "type": "place",
                "startTime": "20121212T000000+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T071430+0200",
                "place": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "type": "unknown",
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 55.55555,
                        "lon": 33.33333
                    }
                },
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            },
            {
                "type": "move",
                "startTime": "20121212T071430+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T074617+0200",
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "activity": "walking",
                        "group": "walking",
                        "manual": false,
                        "startTime": "20121212T071430+0200",
                        "endTime": "20121212T072732+0200",
                        "duration": 782,
                        "distance": 1251,
                        "steps": 1353,
                        "calories": 99,
                        "trackPoints": [
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T071430+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T072732+0200"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "activity": "transport",
                        "group": "transport",
                        "manual": false,
                        "startTime": "20121212T072732+0200",
                        "endTime": "20121212T074616+0200",
                        "duration": 1124,
                        "distance": 8443,
                        "trackPoints": [
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T072732+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T074208+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T074617+0200"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            },
            {
                "type": "place",
                "startTime": "20121212T074617+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T100051+0200",
                "place": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "type": "unknown",
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 55.55555,
                        "lon": 33.33333
                    }
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "activity": "walking_on_treadmill",
                        "group": "walking",
                        "manual": true,
                        "duration": 270,
                        "steps": 303,
                        "calories": 30,
                        "trackPoints": []
                    }
                ],
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            },
            {
                "type": "move",
                "startTime": "20121212T100051+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T100715+0200",
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "activity": "walking",
                        "group": "walking",
                        "manual": false,
                        "startTime": "20121212T100051+0200",
                        "endTime": "20121212T100715+0200",
                        "duration": 384,
                        "distance": 421,
                        "steps": 488,
                        "calories": 99,
                        "trackPoints": [
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T100051+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T100715+0200"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            },
            {
                "type": "place",
                "startTime": "20121212T100715+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T110530+0200",
                "place": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "test",
                    "type": "foursquare",
                    "foursquareId": "4df0fdb17d8ba370a011d24c",
                    "foursquareCategoryIds": ["4bf58dd8d48988d125941735"],
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 55.55555,
                        "lon": 33.33333
                    }
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "activity": "walking",
                        "group": "walking",
                        "manual": false,
                        "startTime": "20121212T101215+0200",
                        "endTime": "20121212T101255+0200",
                        "duration": 40,
                        "distance": 18,
                        "steps": 37,
                        "calories": 99,
                        "trackPoints": [
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T101215+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T101255+0200"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            },
            {
                "type": "move",
                "startTime": "20121212T110530+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T111129+0200",
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "activity": "walking",
                        "group": "walking",
                        "manual": false,
                        "startTime": "20121212T110530+0200",
                        "endTime": "20121212T111128+0200",
                        "duration": 358,
                        "distance": 493,
                        "steps": 441,
                        "calories": 99,
                        "trackPoints": [
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T110531+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T110536+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T110947+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T111017+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T111129+0200"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            },
            {
                "type": "place",
                "startTime": "20121212T111129+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T153638+0200",
                "place": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "type": "unknown",
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 55.55555,
                        "lon": 33.33333
                    }
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "activity": "zumba",
                        "manual": true,
                        "duration": 570,
                        "calories": 200,
                        "trackPoints": []
                    }
                ],
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            },
            {
                "type": "move",
                "startTime": "20121212T153638+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T160744+0200",
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "activity": "underground",
                        "group": "transport",
                        "manual": false,
                        "startTime": "20121212T153638+0200",
                        "endTime": "20121212T155321+0200",
                        "duration": 1003,
                        "distance": 8058,
                        "trackPoints": [
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T153638+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T155322+0200"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "activity": "walking",
                        "group": "walking",
                        "manual": false,
                        "startTime": "20121212T155322+0200",
                        "endTime": "20121212T160744+0200",
                        "duration": 862,
                        "distance": 1086,
                        "steps": 1257,
                        "calories": 99,
                        "trackPoints": [
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T155322+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T155402+0200"
                            },
                            {
                                "lat": 55.55555,
                                "lon": 33.33333,
                                "time": "20121212T160744+0200"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            },
            {
                "type": "place",
                "startTime": "20121212T160744+0200",
                "endTime": "20121212T232730+0200",
                "place": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "type": "unknown",
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 55.55555,
                        "lon": 33.33333
                    }
                },
                "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
            }
        ],
        "caloriesIdle": 1785,
        "lastUpdate": "20130317T121143Z"
    }
]
```

**StorylineData** (Class in which I am trying to parse JSON. Linked to other classes providing parse data and used to create ArrayLists of custom objects from previously parsed JSON)

```
 /**
     * Parse a {@link org.json.JSONObject} from storyline {@link org.json.JSONArray}, then return the corresponding {@link StorylineData} object.
     *
     * @param jsonObject : the storyline JSON object received from server
     * @return corresponding {@link StorylineData}
     */
    public static StorylineData parse(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        if (jsonObject != null) {

        StorylineData storylineData = new StorylineData();

    storylineData.date = jsonObject.optString("date");
    storylineData.caloriesIdle = jsonObject.optInt("caloriesIdle");
    storylineData.lastUpdate = jsonObject.optString("lastUpdate");
    storylineData.summary = new ArrayList<>();
    storylineData.segments = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray summariesJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("summary");

    if (summariesJsonArray != null)
    for (int i = 0; i < summariesJsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject summaryJsonObject = summariesJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

                if (summaryJsonObject != null) {
                summariesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance");

                    String group = summaryJsonObject.optString("group");

                    Integer distance = summaryJsonObject.optInt("distance");
                    storylineData.setDistance(distance);
...
                    storylineData.summary.add(SummaryData.parse(summaryJsonObject));

                    Log.d("StorylineDataCls \t sJo", summaryJsonObject.toString() + "Log\n");
                    System.out.println("print distance" + summariesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance"));       
                    System.out.println("print summary" + summaryJsonObject);

            }
        }

    JSONArray segmentsJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("segments");
    if (segmentsJsonArray != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < segmentsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject segment = segmentsJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

            if (segment != null) {

                JSONArray activitiesJsonArray = segment.optJSONArray("activities");
                if (activitiesJsonArray!=null) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < activitiesJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject trackPoints = activitiesJsonArray.optJSONObject(j);
                        if(trackPoints != null){
                    ...
                storylineData.trackPoints.add(TrackPointsData.parse(trackPoints));
                             }
                    }
                }

        ..
                Log.d("StorylineDataCls \t sSo", segment.toString());
                System.out.println("print segment" + segment);
                //System.out.println("print segments" + segments);
                System.out.println("print segmentsJsonArray" + segmentsJsonArray);

            }
        }
    }


    return storylineData;
}
return null;


}
```

Comment: I recommend you taking a look at Gson library, it just populates your models with the json data, even the nested objects.http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks but isn't that the same as using Jackson library? If so it would involve a huge amount of changes to my HTTP class retrieving data from the server, a large number of case statements, Handler class  and and inner Handler classes.

Comment: Your right, Jackson works the same way, then why are you having problems? your code looks like you are getting the values manually. Can you post your model classes?

Comment: @Nanoc Here is a link to my previous post where I have included the model classes. Let me know if that's ok or if you prefer me to include model classes in this question? Thanks. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583045/android-app-returning-inner-arrays-as-or-arraylist-memory-allocation]

Comment: Thats not the way i thought, you are implementing a parse method where you get the values, thats not needed with gson, and when looking at Jackson doc it looks like isnt needed too.

Comment: Yes many aspects of how the parse methods are implemented are not required with Jackson/Gson. However as I'm new to android every attempt I've made with Jackson to edit non model classes hasn't worked. Any suggestions on how to amend my projects MovesAPI, HTTPClass, MainActivity Handlers etc in order to implement Jackson? I already have Model classes created using Jackson.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95573/discussion-between-dbo-and-nanoc).